# A bold plus symbol in math mode

Tags: math-mode, symbols, bold

I'd like to use a different `+` symbol in addition to `+` in math mode, preferably one which is just bolder than the standard one.

I'm currently using `\pmb{+}` from the `amsbsy` package, but it's a bit too lean for my taste, and it looks a bit pointy to the ends.

I am aware of `\ding{58}` from the `pifont` package, as well as `\Plus` from `bbding`, both of which seem to be non-math mode symbols, and look really bad next to math symbols.

Am I missing some other option to produce a bold +, apart from drawing the symbol myself?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I caved in and went for the drawing option, which is shown below. Surely this is not optimal, as it does not adapt in any way to the font size used, which should probably be done by adjusting the scale factor. If there is any neat way to do so, it would be interesting to learn.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\Plus}{\mathord{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0ex, line width=1, scale=0.13]
\draw (1,0) -- (1,2);
\draw (0,1) -- (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}}}
\begin{document}
$A \Plus B$
\end{document}
```

[image: A bold Plus]

Comment: `\newcommand{\Plus}{\mathord{\tikz\draw[line width=0.3ex, x=1ex, y=1ex] (0.5,0) -- (0.5,1)(0,0.5) -- (1,0.5);}}` should scale with text size.

Answer (score 14):

You can us `bm` to access the bold `+` from the font used for `\boldmath` (which in the standard setup is the font used for `\bfseries` in text.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
\showoutput
$1 + 2 \bm{+} 3$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

You could use `\boldsymbol`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\Huge
$ +\boldsymbol{+}$
\end{document}
```

[image: ++]

Unfortunately it's not that much bolder.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsbsy}
\newcommand*{\myplus}{\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{\pmb{+}}}}
\begin{document}
$\boldsymbol{\pmb{+}}$ $\pmb{+}$ 
$\myplus$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Sorry, can't help for pointy ends! :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's go for another necromancer badge...

If you really want to go *really* bold...

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\Plus}{\mathord{\text{\ding{58}}}}
\begin{document}
$A \Plus B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Yep. It's uglier than ugly. Guilty.)