# mhchem charge of ions too thin

Tags: printing, mhchem

I am using mhchem to write chemical reaction such as the following : `\ce{H2SO4 ->[H2O] 2H^+ + SO4^{2-}}`. It works fine, but when it comes to print it on paper the charges of the ions (+ and - symbols) are so thin that + symbol appears as being almost the same as - symbols. The printed results depends a lot on the printer, but on the institutional one, I will have to  use (no choice), + and - are really close. I am writing an exam and this issue is quite important to me.

So my question is how can I make the rendering of those symbols thicker so that those symbols can be easily discriminate?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75987/47927) or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/254911/47927) can help? But maybe you should just change the font?

Comment: Thank you @Jasper. Not all the methods given in the links you gave work, but the two following from [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75987/47927) works  just fine :   1: \newcommand{\Plus} and
2: \newcommand*{\myplus}

Comment: This need a modification of the font's + sign, I'd say. Easiest solution would be to use a bolder (i.e. non-serif) font, if that is an option for you.