# How to make in Bold the (+ and -) of vsource in tikzcircuit

Tags: circuitikz

How to make in Bold the (+ and -) of vsource in tikzcircuit

[image: +/- in bold in vsource]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What the automatic comment means is that it would be helpful if you can post the full LaTeX code of a document that contains the example diagram. This would make it easier to reproduce and to test potential answers.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are using `circuitikz` (because you tagged so --- would you please provide an example next time, or if my answer is not the one you are looking for?). Moreover, I suppose you are using standard fonts and `pdflatex`.

In that case, you can use the keys shown around page 75 in the (current) manual:

[image]

So, for example (I fixed the units also so that they use standard SI typesetting)

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages, american]{circuitikz}

\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/inner plus={\boldmath $+$}}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/inner minus={\boldmath $-$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw (0,0) to[V, l=\qty{24}{\volt}] ++(0,3)
        to[R=\qty{5}{\ohm}] ++(3,0)
        to[R, l_=\qty{10}{\ohm}, v^=$V$]
        ++(0,-3) to[short, -*] (0,0) node[ground]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that, anyway, the bold plus and minus are, at least with standard math font, not so bold... you can [have a look here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75987/a-bold-plus-symbol-in-math-mode) for some suggestions, or, if you want to go *really* bold:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages, american]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{pifont}

\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/inner plus=\ding{58}}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/inner minus=\rotatebox{90}{\ding{121}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw (0,0) to[V, l=\qty{24}{\volt}] ++(0,3)
        to[R=\qty{5}{\ohm}] ++(3,0)
        to[R, l_=\qty{10}{\ohm}, v^=$V$]
        ++(0,-3) to[short, -*] (0,0) node[ground]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you also want to change the symbols in the voltage indication (but please, do *not* use `pifont` for that !), you can use the settings found on page 207:

[image]

Comment: I guess he want the plus and minus sign for the right side ‘resistor’ also in bold.

Comment: @Tom not sure, but I added to the answer the relevant manual excerpt.